# continue realtime counting from a certain time

Tags: java, android, timer, real-time

I have app that will count some time. The start time will be stored in a database. I want the app to realtime counting from a certain time which will be the time the user started the app.

```
private void countTime(String inDate){
    onStartControll = true;
    long inDateInt = Long.parseLong(inDate);
    long dateNow = Long.parseLong(String.format("%02d",date.getTime()));
    long timeCounted = dateNow - inDateInt;

    startTime = timeCounted;
    timeInMilliseconds = timeCounted;
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(onStartControll == false) {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        } 

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = (int) (secs / 60);
        int minsShown = secs / 60 % 60;
        int hours = (int) (mins / 60);
        secs = secs % 60;

        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 100);
        timerValue.setText(String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minsShown) + ":"
                 + String.format("%02d", secs));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

The problem is the timer do not continue count when i start it.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: O yeah the problem is that the app never continue counting when i open/start it. @BojanKseneman

Comment: customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0); increase the value, you are blocking the UI

Comment: It didn't help, it don't count i realtime. @BojanKseneman

Comment: Android is not a realtime OS.

Comment: I mean the timer is live, the user can se when the secounds and the minutes count. I want it to be visible. Atm is just shows how many h and mins from start until start time @BojanKseneman

Comment: If you are showing minutes and seconds only, updating your UI on 100ms is more than good enough